# Force "visit full site" link to show full site all the time

Tags: javascript, php, redirect, mobile

Here's my code. someone was having problems with the PHP redirect, so I just through a JS one in there and commented out the other one.

So when I'm on my phone (WP8), if I have "prefer mobile sites" on, I get stuck on the mobile site "m.smsalem.com", even with this code below. However, if I change it to "prefer desktop sites", I get the mobile site first, can click "visit full site", and I can then view the regular site.

Any idea what else I can do to *force* people who have "prefer mobile site" set to visit the regular site if they click on that link?

```
<?php
include 'http://smsalem.com/Mobile_Detect.php';
$detect = new Mobile_Detect();

if(strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], 'm.smsalem.com')){
    setcookie("noMobile", true, time()+86400);  /* expire in 1 hour */
}

if ($detect->isMobile()) {
    if(!isset($_COOKIE['noMobile'])){
        ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            if (screen.width <= 700) {
            window.location = "http://m.smsalem.com";
        }
    </script>
    <?php
        //header('Location: m.smsalem.com');
        //exit(0);
      }
} ?>
```

Comment: You can't call `header()` after output has already been sent (from what we can see)

Comment: That's not the issue. Without the JS there, `header()` was working fine for me, but not my colleague. I think they didn't dl the new version of the files though.

Again, the question is "regardless of redirect 'method', how can I force mobile users to remain on the standard site when the click the "view full site" link"?

I'd like the mobile site guys to add a query string to the Full Site link, but they're a pain in the arse to work with.

Comment: the cookie you set in `setcookie()` will NOT be available in $_COOKIE until the **NEXT** hit on your server. the superglobals are set up and populated at script startup, and then NOT touched again by PHP for the duration of the script's execution.

Answer (score 0):

Like already mentioned by Marc B, the cookie you set is not available until you do a refresh. If you only set your cookie for one hour, then why not use a `SESSION`, which is directly available.

You code would then look like this:

```
<?php
include 'http://smsalem.com/Mobile_Detect.php';
$detect = new Mobile_Detect();

if(strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], 'm.smsalem.com')){
    $_SESSION["noMobile"] = true;
}

if ($detect->isMobile()) {
    if(!isset($_SESSION["noMobile"])){
        ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            if (screen.width <= 700) {
            window.location = "http://m.smsalem.com";
        }
    </script>
    <?php
        //header('Location: m.smsalem.com');
        //exit(0);
      }
} ?>
```

Personally I would use the PHP `header()` to redirect the user. But then you won't be able to check the screen width before redirecting.